# Access to environment variables in Vue app in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack, environment-variables

I am building an app in Vue for the front and Node for the back and I am using environment variables for private API keys. The .env file are in the root for my global project and locally I am using Dotenv-Webpack to access them in my front.

Locally everything is working but when I am deploying the app in Heroku, the variables are *undefined*

Here is the structure of my project

```
client
  -> public
  -> src
     -> components
     -> assets
     ...
  ...
routes
services
tests
...
.env
```

And here is the configuration of my vue.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");

module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ["vuetify"],
  outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "../public"),
  devServer: {
    proxy: "http://localhost:5000"
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new Dotenv({
        path: "../.env", // load this now instead of the ones in '.env'
        systemvars: true
      })
    ]
  }
};
```

Does anyone have an idea ? Just to reminder, it can access my .env in my components locally but not when I deploy the app in Heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - you need to define your env vars in heroku.
Check this out
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

2- don't commit your `.env` file in any way.

3- heroku doesn't use the .env file you use localy.
So path property in your config have no effect.

4- keep the `systemvars : true`  as it will load all the system vars which is the env vars you defined in heroku dashboard/CLI

Comment: It doesn't work. I still have an _undefined_ in the Vue app when I try to access the env vars at the root of the project (.env of the back)

Comment: did you define the same vars exist in .env file into heroku vars ?

Comment: Yes, I got exactly the same vars between my .env file and heroku vars

Comment: wait. did you say **I am using Dotenv-Webpack to access them in my front.** ? you can't access `process.env` in not a nodejs environment. heroku it's production environment and the front end that is served to the clients have no environment variables, no .env file, no nodejs process .   @tboll

Comment: ok sounds clear ! So it's not possible to share back-end env vars with front-end ? And if I want to, I need to duplicate these vars in a specific .env in my front-end ?

Comment: @tboll,  
**private API keys** should never be used in the front end. they will be exposed to anyone opened your website. only use them in the back end. 
if this answered your question. then approve my answer. thanks